# Why do kableExtra and modelsummary interact weirdly?

Tags: latex, quarto, kableextra, modelsummary

I am working on a Quarto project and use R for statistical analyses, modelsummary to format the output tables and kableExtra to style those accordingly.

However, when using modelsummary with kableExtra, I am encountering a weird error where the output in the PDF is the raw LaTeX code for the table, but not the (rendered) table itself:

I encounter this problem specifically when calling `kbl()`:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(modelsummary)

model <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
modelsummary(model) |> 
    kbl() |> 
    kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)
```

When I skip `kbl()`, there is no problem - but I need some functionality of `kbl()` (e.g., `longtable` and `booktabs`). I already tried modifying the code blocks output, i.e. `#| output: asis` as well as all different combinations of modelsummary's `format` argument and `kbl()`'s `output` argument. Nothing seems to work - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

These two packages work well together, use this code to make it work:

```
modelsummary(model, output = "kableExtra") |> 
    kable_styling(full_width=TRUE)
```

### for pdf

```
modelsummary(model, output = "data.frame") |>
  kbl(format = "latex") |> 
  kable_styling(full_width=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! But how would I use the arguments longtable and booktabs in the kbl() function?

Comment: you can change the output to "data.frame" and then use the usual kable pipeline.

Comment: I again tried it with output="kableExtra" but now received HTML output in my LaTeX table..

Comment: I made an edit..